# C++ Calculating Shortest Path in a Directed Graph

Tags: c++, constants, nodes, shortest-path, directed-graph

I am tasked with writing a program to maintain the representation of a simple network(weighted directed graph) and compute the best path between two given nodes upon request.

Currently, I am attempting to write a function to compute the simplest between two nodes, however, when attempting to run my program, I get two specific error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3863   array type 'bool [openNode]' is not assignable  P   127
```

and

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C3863   array type 'int [openNode]' is not assignable
```

I am unable to debug since these two primary errors are not allowing my program to run. Is there any particular reason for these errors?

Thanks in advance!

This is the node structure defined in Graph.h

```
struct GraphNode
{
    char ID;
    std::string name;
    int inNodes = 0;
    int outNodes = 0;
    std::vector<std::pair<GraphNode*, int>> connection;
    int  connections = 0;
};
```

And here is the particular code that causes the errors.

```
#include "Graph.h"

std::vector<GraphNode*> _graph;
int openNode = 0;

//Obligatory constructor
void Graph()
{

}

void shortestPath(char fromNode, char toNode)
{
    bool known[openNode];
    int distance[openNode];
    GraphNode*  previous[openNode];
    int numbChecked = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < openNode; i++)
    {
        known[i] = false;
        distance[i] = 999999;
        previous[i] = nullptr;
    }

    distance[findNode(fromNode)] = 0;

    while (numbChecked < openNode)
    {
        int smallestUnknown = 9999999;
        int locationOfSmall = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < openNode; i++)
        {
            if (known[i] == false && distance[i] < smallestUnknown)
            {
                smallestUnknown = distance[i];
                locationOfSmall = i;
            }
        }

        if (distance[locationOfSmall] == 0)
        {
            previous[locationOfSmall] = nullptr;
        }

        known[locationOfSmall] = true;
        numbChecked++;

        if (_graph[locationOfSmall]->outNodes > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _graph[locationOfSmall]->outNodes; i++)
            {
                int newDistanceLocation = findNode(_graph[locationOfSmall]->connection[i].first->ID);
                if (known[newDistanceLocation] == false && (distance[locationOfSmall] + _graph[locationOfSmall]->connection[i].second) < distance[newDistanceLocation])
                {
                    distance[newDistanceLocation] = distance[locationOfSmall] + _graph[locationOfSmall]->connection[i].second;
                    previous[newDistanceLocation] = _graph[locationOfSmall];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int destination = findNode(toNode);
    std::string output;
    std::string charTransfer;
    charTransfer = toNode;
    output = charTransfer;

    while (previous[destination] != nullptr)
    {
        destination = findNode(previous[destination]->ID);
        charTransfer = _graph[destination]->ID;
        output = charTransfer + "->" + output;
    }

    if (_graph[destination]->ID != fromNode)
    {
        std::cout << "The nodes are not connected." << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "The path is: " << output << std::endl;
        std::cout << "The distance is: " << distance[findNode(toNode)] << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Any change suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a part of code, where you change openNode variable?

Comment: There is. Within my addnode function 

void addNode(std::string nameIn)
{
 //Add data to graph
 GraphNode* holder = new GraphNode;
 holder->ID = (char)('A' + openNode);
 holder->name = nameIn;
 _graph.push_back(holder);
 openNode++;
 std::cout << "The node added has the ID: " << holder->ID << std::endl;
}

Answer (score 2):

You have invalid code at the beginning of your `shortestPath` function:

```
bool known[openNode];
int distance[openNode];
GraphNode*  previous[openNode];
```

You cannot use variables to create arrays on the stack (which is what you are trying to do there), because the compiler doesn't know the value of `openNode` at compile time (which is needed to determine the stack size).

Why don't you use a vector, like:

```
std::vector<bool> known(openNode, false);
std::vector<int> distance(openNode, 999999);
std::vector<GraphNode*>  previous(openNode, nullptr);
```

Using this method makes the for loop below obsolete aswell.

Comment: Would I still need my numbChecked variable?

Comment: @Granzo I didn't analyze your algorithm, I just showed a fix for your compiler error (which was your question). If you also need verification on your algorithm you may rephrase your question. So your variables have the same effect as before and you have to use them as before.

Comment: Gotcha. I will try this first then rephrase if needed! Thanks!